# TCP client/server not working

Tags: sockets, tcp, autoit

I made a TCP client and -server using AutoIt. However, when I send `welcome` it's never received. I'm not sure why. The code is:

```
#include <Array.au3>
Global $Socket
Global $Recibe
Global $IP
Global $sDnsAddr = "address"
Global $PORT = 1234

$IP = TCPNameToIP($sDnsAddr)

While 1 ;Reconeccion
    _Conectar()
    TCPSend($Socket, "Hola")
    While 1 ; Recibir y ejecutar
        $Recibe = ""
        While $Recibe = ""
            $Recibe = TCPRecv($Socket, 10000000)
            Sleep(100)
        WEnd
        $Dat = StringSplit($Recibe, "|||")
        Select
            Case $Dat[1] = "Welcome"
                TCPSend("Hola que tal")
        EndSelect
    WEnd
WEnd

Func _Conectar()
    While TCPStartup() = 0
        Sleep(10)
    WEnd
    While True
        $Socket = TCPConnect($IP, $PORT)
        If $Socket > 0 Then
            Ejemplo()
            ExitLoop
        EndIf
        Sleep(1000)
    WEnd
EndFunc
```

I want to send a message and receive a reply. Something like this:

[image]

But the result is:

[image]

Sending the first TCP message makes my script crash. I tried using `127.0.0.1` but that doesn't work either:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Start server first: Port 33891

Compile the Client or the server to exe. Then start Server first, and then client e.g. from Scite4Autoit.

```
;SERVER!! Start Me First !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
#include <GUIConstants.au3>

; Initialize a variable to represent a connection
;==============================================
Global $MainSocket, $ConnectedSocket = -1
Global $g_IP = @IPAddress1
Global $g_port = 33891

; Start The TCP Services
;==============================================
TCPStartup()

; Create a Listening "SOCKET"
;==============================================
$MainSocket = TCPListen($g_IP, $g_port, 100)
If $MainSocket = -1 Then Exit
$RogueSocket = -1

; Create a GUI for chatting
;==============================================
$GOOEY = GUICreate("my server - I am " & @IPAddress1, 350, 200, @DesktopWidth / 2 + 100, @DesktopHeight / 2 - 350)
$edit = GUICtrlCreateEdit("", 10, 40, 330, 150, $WS_DISABLED)
$input = GUICtrlCreateInput("", 10, 10, 250, 20)
$butt = GUICtrlCreateButton("Send", 260, 10, 80, 20, $BS_DEFPUSHBUTTON)
GUISetState()

; GUI Message Loop
;==============================================
While 1
    $msg = GUIGetMsg()

    ; GUI Closed
    ;--------------------
    If $msg = $GUI_EVENT_CLOSE Then ExitLoop

    ; User Pressed SEND
    ;--------------------
    If $msg = $butt Then
        If $ConnectedSocket > - 1 Then
            $ret = TCPSend($ConnectedSocket, GUICtrlRead($input))
            If @error Then
                ; ERROR OCCURRED, CLOSE SOCKET AND RESET ConnectedSocket to -1
                ;----------------------------------------------------------------
                TCPCloseSocket($ConnectedSocket)
                WinSetTitle($GOOEY, "", "my server - I am " & @IPAddress1)
                $ConnectedSocket = -1
            ElseIf $ret > 0 Then
                ; UPDATE EDIT CONTROL WITH DATA WE SENT
                ;----------------------------------------------------------------
                GUICtrlSetData($edit, GUICtrlRead($edit) & GUICtrlRead($input) & @CRLF)
            EndIf
        EndIf
        GUICtrlSetData($input, "")
    EndIf

    If $RogueSocket > 0 Then
        $recv = TCPRecv($RogueSocket, 512)
        If Not @error Then
            TCPCloseSocket($RogueSocket)
            $RogueSocket = -1
        EndIf
    EndIf

    ; If no connection look for one
    ;--------------------
    If $ConnectedSocket = -1 Then
        $ConnectedSocket = TCPAccept($MainSocket)
        If $ConnectedSocket >= 0 Then
            WinSetTitle($GOOEY, "", "my server - Hello " & SOCKET2IP($ConnectedSocket))
        EndIf

        ; If connected try to read some data
        ;--------------------
    Else
        ; EXECUTE AN UNCONDITIONAL ACCEPT IN CASE ANOTHER CLIENT TRIES TO CONNECT
        ;----------------------------------------------------------------
        $RogueSocket = TCPAccept($MainSocket)
        If $RogueSocket > 0 Then
            TCPSend($RogueSocket, "~~rejected")
        EndIf

        $recv = TCPRecv($ConnectedSocket, 512)

        If $recv <> "" And $recv <> "~~bye" Then
            ; UPDATE EDIT CONTROL WITH DATA WE RECEIVED
            ;----------------------------------------------------------------
            GUICtrlSetData($edit, GUICtrlRead($edit) & ">" & $recv & @CRLF)

        ElseIf @error Or $recv = "~~bye" Then
            ; ERROR OCCURRED, CLOSE SOCKET AND RESET ConnectedSocket to -1
            ;----------------------------------------------------------------
            WinSetTitle($GOOEY, "", "my server - I am " & @IPAddress1)
            TCPCloseSocket($ConnectedSocket)
            $ConnectedSocket = -1
        EndIf
    EndIf
WEnd

GUIDelete($GOOEY)

Func OnAutoItExit()
    ;ON SCRIPT EXIT close opened sockets and shutdown TCP service
    ;----------------------------------------------------------------------
    If $ConnectedSocket > - 1 Then
        TCPSend($ConnectedSocket, "~~bye")
        Sleep(2000)
        TCPRecv($ConnectedSocket, 512)
        TCPCloseSocket($ConnectedSocket)
    EndIf
    TCPCloseSocket($MainSocket)
    TCPShutdown()
EndFunc   ;==>OnAutoItExit

Func SOCKET2IP($SHOCKET)
    Local $sockaddr = DllStructCreate("short;ushort;uint;char[8]")

    $a = DllCall("Ws2_32.dll", "int", "getpeername", "int", $SHOCKET, "ptr", DllStructGetPtr($sockaddr), _
            "int_ptr", DllStructGetSize($sockaddr))
    If Not @error And $a[0] = 0 Then
        $a = DllCall("Ws2_32.dll", "str", "inet_ntoa", "int", DllStructGetData($sockaddr, 3))
        If Not @error Then $a = $a[0]
    Else
        $a = 0
    EndIf

    ; release Struct not really needed as it is a local
    $sockaddr = 0

    Return $a
EndFunc   ;==>SOCKET2IP
```

Client

```
#include <GuiConstants.au3>
#include <GuiEdit.au3>
#include <Misc.au3>
Local $Server = InputBox("Server", "Please input the server you would like to connect to:")
Local $Port = InputBox("Server Port", "Please input the port or the server you would like to connect to:")
TCPStartup()
$MainSocket = TCPConnect(TCPNameToIP($Server), $Port)
If $MainSocket = -1 Then Exit MsgBox(0, "Error", "Could Not Connect or Bad Connection")
GUICreate("Server Client", 390, 210)
$Send = GUICtrlCreateEdit("", 10, 10, 175, 150, $WS_VSCROLL)
Local $History = GUICtrlCreateEdit("Server Messages:", 200, 10, 175, 150, BitOR($WS_VSCROLL, $ES_READONLY))
$SButton = GUICtrlCreateButton("Send", 145, 165, 100, 35)
GUISetState()
While 1
    $msg = GUIGetMsg()
    If $msg = $GUI_EVENT_CLOSE Then
        Exit
    ElseIf $msg = $SButton Or _IsPressed ("0D") = 1 Then
        $Text = GUICtrlRead($Send)
        $TCPSent = TCPSend($MainSocket, $Text)
        GUICtrlSetData($Send, "")
    EndIf
    $Recv = TCPRecv($MainSocket, 512)
    If $Recv <> "" Then
        GUICtrlSetData($History, GUICtrlRead($History) & @CRLF & $Recv)
        _GUICtrlEdit_LineScroll ($History, 0, _GUICtrlEdit_GetLineCount ($History))
    EndIf
WEnd
Func OnAutoItExit()
    TCPCloseSocket($MainSocket)
    TCPShutdown()
EndFunc;==>OnAutoItExit
```